# Difficulties in understanding the horns and skeletons of simplicial sets

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am currently reading Goerss and Jardine's book 'Simplicial Homotopy Theory and I am struggling to understand some of the definitions the book introduces early on.
In particular I am struggling to understand the definition of the $nth$ skeleton $sk_nX$ of a simplicial set $X$ (defined on page 8 as: the subcomplex of $X$ which is generated by the simplices of $X$ of degree $\leq n$), and the $kth$ horn $\Lambda^n_k$ of the simplicial set $\Delta^n$ (defined on page 6 as the subcomplex of $\Delta^n$ which is generated by all faces $d_j(1_n)$ except the $kth$ face $d_k(1_n)$).
To aid in developing an understanding of these definitions I am trying to construct simple examples.
So lets consider the simplicial set $\Delta^3$ and its $2nd$ skeleton $sk_2\Delta^3$.
Then we have that
\begin{align}
\left(sk_2\Delta^3\right)_{0} & = \text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{3}), \\
\left(sk_2\Delta^3\right)_{1} & = \text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{3}), \text{and}\\
\left(sk_2\Delta^3\right)_{2} & = \text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{2},\mathbf{3}). \\
\end{align}
Working out what the set $\left(sk_2\Delta^3\right)_{3}$ precisely contains is where I am encountering an issue.
The best I can possibly seem to guess is that it contains all the maps $f:\mathbf{3} \to \mathbf{3}$ such that $f = d^i\circ s^j$ for some $i$ and $j$. Then I assume $\left(sk_2\Delta^3\right)_{4}$ contains maps $g:\mathbf{4} \to \mathbf{3}$ such that $g = d^i\circ s^j \circ s^k$ for some $i,j,k$. And so on. Is this correct? If not where am I going wrong?

In the case of simplicial horns I am trying to consider the $0th$ horn of $\Delta^3$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\left(\Lambda_0^3\right)_{0} & = \text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{3}), \\
\left(\Lambda_0^3\right)_{1} & = \text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{3}), \text{and} \\
\left(\Lambda_0^3\right)_{2} & = \text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{2},\mathbf{3})\setminus\{d^0\}. \\
\end{align}
Working out what maps the set $\left(\Lambda_0^3\right)_{3}$ precisely contains is where I am struggling. Using my above idea figure that $\left(\Lambda_0^3\right)_{3}$ contains all maps $f:\mathbf{3} \to \mathbf{3}$ such that $f = d^i\circ s^j$ for some $i \not = 0$ and $j$.
Then I assume $\left(\Lambda_0^3\right)_{4} $ contains maps $g:\mathbf{4} \to \mathbf{3}$ such that $g = d^i\circ s^j \circ s^k$ for some $i \not = 0,j,k$. And so on. Again, is this correct? If not where am I going wrong?

I fear I have totally misunderstood the definitions and I am struggling with finding a source that gives me a simple example of both that I can understand. Any help fixing my above examples and improving my understanding of the definitions overall would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: $\left(sk_2\Delta^3\right)_{3}$ consists of every element of $\text{hom}_{\Delta}(\mathbf{3},\mathbf{3})$ except the identity map.

Comment: Basically what it means for a simplicial set S' to be generated by some set S'' of simplices of a simplicial set S is that $x \in S' _n$ iff $S(\theta)(s'')=x$ for some $\theta : [n] \rightarrow [m]$ and $s'' \in S_m$ and $s'' \in S''$ for some m. Or alternatively S' is the "smallest" simplicial set containing all of the simplices in S'' where for X,Y simplicial sets X is smaller than Y iff $X_n \subset Y_n$ and the inclusion $X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of simplicial sets.